# How Can I add unlimited elements in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, element

I'm working on a website on C# and ASP.Net, and I want to make a button for adding extra fields every time you pressing it, then I want to save the values.
What I want to do is something similar to this example : http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/examples/2/1/#

When you press the "Add your favorite links....." is adding new elements

Anyone who can help me?

Thank you

Comment: Right-click -> View page source -> Done.

Comment: Sounds like a "plz send me the codes" question to me.

Comment: The nerdy answer is: you can't. Sooner or later you will run out of of memory, disk space or address space -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use .NET MVC, you can following Phil Haack

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Can you use jQuery?

```
var currentIndex = 0;
$("#yourButton").click(function() {
    var target = $("#yourTargetDiv");
    target.append($("<span>" + ++currentIndex + "</span>");
    target.append($("<input type='text' />");
});
```